# File_get_contents is not defined error in Apache server

Tags: php, json, apache

I wrote a simple script to get content of a page.
When I am running it on Apache server, I'm getting an error:

> file_get_contents is not defined

Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3.9. Here is the code:

```
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&country=PL&currency=3&market_hash_name=Desert%20Eagle%20%7C%20Blaze%20(Minimal%20Wear)";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$price = json_decode($json);
alert(price.lowest_price);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Uhm, what ? ........ that seems impossible ?

Comment: it may be possible. are you running this locally?

Comment: @unixmiah Yes, I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're local that may be an issue. In your php.ini file try to add

```
allow_url_fopen = 1
```

and re-try. I like to use cURL if I have to grab a file. Here is really simple example of file grabbing remotely.

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

The Usage

```
$returned_content = get_data('http://www.grab.com/grab-me.html');
```

This is guaranteed to work whether or not you're having issues with file_get_contents

Comment: whar are you using? xampp or wamp? is it on windows? how do you have your lamp setup?

Comment: "allow_url_fopen = 1" doesn't help. Should I run it on a online server?

And when I try to run your cURL example, I am getting an error: curl_init is not defined. I really want to make this work with no libraries. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm just using Apache with PHP, not XAMPP or WAMP.